# Simple DataTrigger not Working. Why?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, triggers, datatrigger

I am trying to change the foreground color of a text block based on a bool property that its value is changed when a button is clicked. However, for some reason this is not working. Also, do I have to add the bool property to a list in first place? I tried adding the bool property directly to the DataContext, but this did not work either. Any help would be appreciated.

> ```
>     public static bool IsOn { get; set; }
> ```

```
    public static List<bool> boo;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsOn = true;
        boo = new List<bool>();
        boo.Add(IsOn); 
        DataContext = boo;                   
    }
```

> ```
> <Window.Resources>
> ```

```
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsOn}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Change Color" />
        <TextBlock Name="textBlockColor" Text="My Foreground Color" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Try with you `DataTrigger` Binding as `Binding="{Binding Path=[0]}"`

Comment: if you set `DataContext = IsOn;` in your click handler then you need your DataTrigger as `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=.}" Value="true">` In either scenario `IsOn` is not a "property" of the `DataContext` object. Hence you can't rly be looking for it. If you create a class containing `IsOn` as a property and set this class object as the `DataContext`, then you can give `Path=IsOn`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)) to notify view that your property was changed.

Second you must assign `DataContext` in `MainWindow` constructor.

Example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private bool _isOn;
    public bool IsOn
    {
        get { return _isOn; }
        set { _isOn = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsOn"); }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsOn = !IsOn;          
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Your XAML code is OK.

When your binding doesn't work you should use [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) in the future.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to add that you don't have to assign  DataContext in the MainWindow constructor. This might be necessary in other cases, which I am currently not aware of at this moment, but in our example, it works fine inside the click event handler.